# Problems creating UICollectionView, resource created multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, ios10

I have successfully created multiple collection views in my main view, create the label programatically inside my cell, but every time the collection view its refreshed it creates new labels that overlay with the previews labels. How can I delete the previous data and create the new resource without overlaying?

[Image 1 -> error displaying collectionview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6mQd.png)

Here is my code.

Outlets for CollectionViews

```
@IBOutlet var collection1: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet var collection2: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet var collection3: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet var collection4: UICollectionView!
```

Delegate for collection

```
collection1.dataSource = self
    collection1.delegate = self
    collection1.register(UICollectionViewCell.self,   forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
    collection1.backgroundColor = collectionBG
    self.view.addSubview(collection1)
```

Collection View Functions

```
 // MARK: - COLLECTIONVIEW FUNC
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count: Int?
    if collectionView == diasSemana{
        count =  dias.count
    }
    if collectionView == collection1{
        count =  instructores.count
    }
    if collectionView == collection2{
        count = instructores.count
    }
    if collectionView == collection3{
        count = instructores.count
    }
    if collectionView == collection4{
        count = instructores.count
    }
    return count!
}

// MARK: - COLLECTIONVIEW FUNC
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell: UICollectionViewCell?

    if collectionView == diasSemana{

        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell


        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(15), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat((cell?.bounds.size.width)!), height: CGFloat(30)))
        //title.addTextSpacing(1.5)
        title.font = UIFont(name:"GothamRounded-Book", size: 11)

        title.tag = 16
        title.text = dias[indexPath.row]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(title)


    }
    if collectionView == collection1{

        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        cell?.backgroundColor = .white
        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(20), y: CGFloat(20), width: CGFloat((cell?.bounds.size.width)!), height: CGFloat(15)))
        //title.addTextSpacing(1.5)
        title.font = UIFont(name:"GothamRounded-Book", size: 11)

        title.tag = 17
        title.text = instructores[indexPath.row]
        //print("have created an new item \(title.text)")
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(title)

        let txt = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(15), y: CGFloat(35), width: CGFloat((cell?.bounds.size.width)!), height: CGFloat(10)))
        //title.addTextSpacing(1.5)
        txt.font = UIFont(name:"GothamRounded-Book", size: 11)

        txt.tag = 18
        txt.text = horas[indexPath.row]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(txt)

    }

    if collectionView == collection2{

        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        cell?.backgroundColor = .white
        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(20), y: CGFloat(20), width: CGFloat((cell?.bounds.size.width)!), height: CGFloat(15)))
        //title.addTextSpacing(1.5)
        title.font = UIFont(name:"GothamRounded-Book", size: 11)

        title.tag = 19
        title.text = instructores[indexPath.row]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(title)

        let txt = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(15), y: CGFloat(35), width: CGFloat((cell?.bounds.size.width)!), height: CGFloat(10)))
        //title.addTextSpacing(1.5)
        txt.font = UIFont(name:"GothamRounded-Book", size: 11)

        txt.tag = 20
        txt.text = horas[indexPath.row]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(txt)

    }

    if collectionView == collection3{
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell3", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        cell?.backgroundColor = .white
        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(20), y: CGFloat(20), width: CGFloat((cell?.bounds.size.width)!), height: CGFloat(15)))
        //title.addTextSpacing(1.5)
        title.font = UIFont(name:"GothamRounded-Book", size: 11)

        title.tag = 21
        title.text = instructores[indexPath.row]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(title)

        let txt = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(15), y: CGFloat(35), width: CGFloat((cell?.bounds.size.width)!), height: CGFloat(10)))
        //title.addTextSpacing(1.5)
        txt.font = UIFont(name:"GothamRounded-Book", size: 11)

        txt.tag = 22
        txt.text = horas[indexPath.row]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(txt)
    }
    if collectionView == collection4{
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell4", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        cell?.backgroundColor = .white
        let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(20), y: CGFloat(20), width: CGFloat((cell?.bounds.size.width)!), height: CGFloat(15)))
        //title.addTextSpacing(1.5)
        title.font = UIFont(name:"GothamRounded-Book", size: 11)

        title.tag = 23
        title.text = instructores[indexPath.row]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(title)

        let txt = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(15), y: CGFloat(35), width: CGFloat((cell?.bounds.size.width)!), height: CGFloat(10)))
        //title.addTextSpacing(1.5)
        txt.font = UIFont(name:"GothamRounded-Book", size: 11)

        txt.tag = 24
        print("----------------------------------------------------\n\n\(horas)")
        print(horas[indexPath.row])
        txt.text = horas[indexPath.row]
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(txt)
    }

    return cell!
}

// MARK: - COLLECTION VIEW FUNC
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView == diasSemana{
        print(dias[indexPath.row])
    }else if collectionView == collection1 {
        print(instructores[indexPath.row])
        self.nombreInstructor = instructores[indexPath.row]
        print(horas[indexPath.row])
        hora = "\(horas[indexPath.row])"
        usrDefaults.set(nombreInstructor, forKey: "INSTRUCTOR")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "clase_Seleccionada", sender: nil)
        dia = "LUN 30"

    }
    if collectionView == collection2{
        print(instructores2[indexPath.row])
        self.nombreInstructor = instructores2[indexPath.row]
        print(horas2[indexPath.row])
        hora = "\(horas2[indexPath.row])"
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "clase_Seleccionada", sender: nil)
        dia = "MAR 31"


    }
    if collectionView == collection3{
        print(instructores3[indexPath.row])
        self.nombreInstructor = instructores3[indexPath.row]
        print(horas3[indexPath.row])
        hora = "\(horas3[indexPath.row])"
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "clase_Seleccionada", sender: nil)
        dia = "MIE 01"


    }
    if collectionView == collection4{
        print(instructores4[indexPath.row])
        self.nombreInstructor = instructores4[indexPath.row]
        print(horas4[indexPath.row])
        hora = "\(horas4[indexPath.row])"
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "clase_Seleccionada", sender: nil)
        dia = "JUE 02"

    }
}
```

And it is refreshed every time one of the above buttons (PARK, 147, Masaryk) its clicked.

Comment: Why you are using multiple collection view on single view.
Go with multiple section in single collection view

Comment: here is a similar question with a solution that is similar to you problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995724/uicollectionview-cell-views-overlapping

Comment: @pradeepchauhan_pc is it possible to have vertical sections?, what i want to do is have a column for each day.

Comment: @KennyGunderman thanks I'll check it, seems to be the solution.